# WordPress - Display Post Content and Post Meta on a Page in the Admin Area

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to create a page in my WordPress Admin Area that displays excerpts of posts and various custom field meta in a table-style layout.

If this were a front-end WordPress Template, I could do this very easily using a WordPress Loop and Query, however, I am not so sure how I would go about doing this on a page in the admin area.

Would it be the same, or would I need to use a completely new method?  If so, could someone please provide a working example of how I would do this?

The admin page will be created using an included file within my functions.php - or at least that is the plan at the moment, so I just need help in figuring out how to pull the WordPress Excerpts and Post Meta.

Comment: You can create your own plugin to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

outside the loop you would need to use

```
$post->post_excerpt
```

or try this

```
function get_the_excerpt_here($post_id)
{
  global $wpdb;
  $query = "SELECT post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = $post_id LIMIT 1";
  $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
  return $result[0]['post_excerpt'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [WP_Query object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) everytime after WordPress is initialized, so if you like you can even make thousands of nested queries in den WordPress backend if you want to do this.

This is the way to go:

1. Create an action to add your backend page - write a Plugin or put it into your functions.php
2. Setup the Menu Page - the code is an example for a **full backend administration Page of your Theme**
3. Include your queries using the WP_Query object - optionally make database queries directly (http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query). Possibly use the "widefat" class of WordPress, for pretty formatting.
4. Make sure that your changes are saved correctly

   ```
           add_action('admin_menu', 'cis_create_menu');

           function cis_create_menu() {

               //create new top-level menu
               add_menu_page(__('Theme Settings Page',TEXTDOMAIN),__('Configure Theme',TEXTDOMAIN), 'administrator', __FILE__, 'cis_settings_page', ''); 

               //call register settings function
               add_action('admin_init','cis_register_settings');
           }


           function cis_register_settings() {
               register_setting('cis-settings-group','cis_options_1','cis_validate_settings');
           }


           function cis_settings_page() {

               // All Text field settings
               $op_fields = array(
                   array(__('Label 1','textdomain'),"Description 1")
               );

           ?>
           <div class="wrap">
               <h2><?php echo THEME_NAME; _e(": Settings",TEXTDOMAIN); ?></h2>

               <?php 
               settings_errors();
               ?>

               <form method="post" action="options.php">
                   <?php 
                       settings_fields( 'cis-settings-group' );
                       $options = get_option('cis_options_1');
                   ?>
                   <h3><?php _e('General','textdomain'); ?></h3>
                   <table class="widefat">
                       <thead>
                           <tr valign="top">
                               <th scope="row"><?php _e('Setting','ultrasimpleshop'); ?></th>
                               <th scope="row"><?php _e('Value','ultrasimpleshop'); ?></th>
                               <th scope="row"><?php _e('Description','ultrasimpleshop'); ?></th>
                               <th scope="row"><?php _e('ID','ultrasimpleshop'); ?></th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                       <?php 
                       // the text-settings we define fast display
                       $i=1;
                       foreach($op_fields as $op) {?>
                           <tr valign="top">
                               <td><label for="cis_oset_<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $op[0]; ?></label></td>
                               <td><input size="100" id="cis_oset_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="cis_options_1[cis_oset_<?php echo $i; ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($options['cis_oset_'.$i]);?>" /></td>
                               <td class="description"><?php echo $op[1]; ?></td>
                               <td class="description"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                           </tr>
                           <?php 
                           $i++;
                       } ?>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>

                   <p class="submit">
                   <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes',TEXTDOMAIN) ?>" /> 
                   </p>

               </form>
           </div>
           <?php }

           // Validate the user input - if nothing to validate, just return
           function cis_validate_settings( $input ) {

               $valid = array();
               $i= 1;
               while(isset($input['cis_oset_'.$i])) {
                   $valid['cis_oset_'.$i] = $input['cis_oset_'.$i];
                   $i++;
               }

               $cis_additional_settings = get_option('cis_options_1');

               foreach($input as $ikey => $ivalue) {
                   if($ivalue != $valid[$ikey]) {
                       add_settings_error(
                           $ikey, // setting title
                           "cis_oset_".$ikey, // error ID
                           str_replace("%s",$ikey,__('Invalid Setting in Settings Area ("%s"). The value was not changed.',TEXTDOMAIN)), // error message
                           'error' // type of message
                       );
                       $valid[$ikey] = $cis_additional_settings[$ikey];
                   }
               }

               return $valid;
           }
   ```

Comment: I'll give this a go in a couple of days and if it works, I'll accept it :)  Thanks so much